# container.lookup deprecation alternative?

Tags: ember.js

Ever since ember 1.12 i get a deprecation notice for this line of code. **Which sits in a component not an initializer.**

```
this.container.lookup('application:main');
```

Notice:

> DEPRECATION: `lookup` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API
>   no longer receives a container, and you should use an
>   `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. See
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers
>   for more details.

What other way is there to get a hold of the main application container?

Comment: what are you trying to do with application:main